# ERROR failed to bootstrap model: bootstrap instance started but did not change to Deployed state: instance "tfraaq" is started but not deployed

Tags: server, maas, landscape

```
juju ended with exit code 1 (out='', err='Adding contents of "/var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/26/ssh/juju_id_rsa.pub" to authorized-keys
Creating Juju controller "26" on landscape-maas
Loading image metadata
Looking for packaged Juju agent version 2.3.4 for amd64
Starting new instance for initial controller
Launching controller instance(s) on landscape-maas...
 - tfraaq (arch=amd64 mem=16G cores=20)
Installing Juju agent on bootstrap instance
Juju GUI installation has been disabled
ERROR failed to bootstrap model: bootstrap instance started but did not change to Deployed state: instance "tfraaq" is started but not deployed
')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are likely running into an integration bug between your maas server and Landscape, which will not be fixed.  :/

Please see the following for the official word on the Openstack "Autopilot" offering in the Landscape tool:

https://insights.ubuntu.com/2014/11/06/putting-your-openstack-on-autopilot/

Specifically, Here is the text from Canonical:

> Thanks for your interest in Ubuntu OpenStack. Canonical has sunsetted
>   OpenStack Autopilot and replaced it with [conjure-up](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/try-openstack). We welcome you to
>   visit our [OpenStack product page](https://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/openstack) to find an Ubuntu OpenStack solution
>   that meets your needs.